# R: Match an odd number of repetitions

Tags: r, regex, escaping, regex-greedy, regexp-replace

I would like to match a string like `\code`, but not when the backslash is escaped.

I think that one way of doing this could be matching an odd number of backslashes. Then for example, assuming `\code` is an expression to be replaced by `1234`:

`\code` would be `1234`, but `\\code`, should stay as is, `\\\code` would be `\\1234`, etc.

In R, given the strings:

```
message(o <- "\\\\\\code")
# \\\code
message(e <- "\\\\code")
# \\code
```

A partially working attempt in R is:

```
message(gsub("((?:\\\\{2})?)\\\\code", "\\11234", o, perl=TRUE))
# \\1234
message(gsub("((?:\\\\{2})*)\\\\code", "\\11234", e, perl=TRUE))
# \1234
```

The regex matches both the odd and even case. To make it work, I should find a way to match the double backslashes, "\", more greedily (always when they are present) so that the second backslash doesn't.

Of course, if there is a better strategy to match a "\sequence" (when not escaped) that would be equally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
rx <- "(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\\K\\\\code"
```

Replace with `1234`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x0W0qU/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)` - fail if there is a `\` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:\\{2})*`  - match and consume 0 or more occurrences of double backslash
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `\\code` - `\code` text.

See an [R demo online](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6hCwUZXQUnD3kYxBgg0NeytQHS1Ua2mVkyMN4idnJ@SqsSVm1pcnJieqpFeXJqkUVSho6BkaGRsogSkY2LgqnQUClKLcmxDgkJdNTUVlBWg4lzKCrZ2QA5IBwGDsBijADYI2RwwG5852B2DMAKk8v9/AA):

```
rx <- "(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\\K\\\\code"
message(gsub(rx, "1234", "\\\\\\code", perl=TRUE)) # \\\code
# => \\1234
message(gsub(rx, "1234", "\\\\code", perl=TRUE))   # \\code
# => \\code
message(gsub(rx, "1234", "\\code", perl=TRUE)) # \code
# => 1234
```

Comment: Thanks, `K` is the killer I did not know about